# Sympy Tensor Index specific value

Tags: sympy, physics, tensor

```
`Lorentz = TensorIndexType('Lorentz', dummy_name='Lorentz')

a, b, c, d = tensor_indices('a b c d', Lorentz)

eta = Matrix([[-1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]])

repl = {}

repl[Lorentz] = eta.tolist()

vec = TensorHead('x', [Lorentz])

repl[vec(a)] = [v_0, v_2, v_3, v_4]
```

when doing a contraction like

`expr = vec(a)*vec(b)`
I can get the values with

`expr.replace_with_arrays(repl, [a,b])`

but how do I evaluate expressions, where I need a specific index, like for example

`expr = vec(0)*vec(b)`

how to do that?;
or even further for to contract only over spacial components

I tried substituting the indices with ".sub", but this obviously didn't work.